# XRDP single session per user

Tags: centos, cinnamon, xrdp

I would love to have a Linux CentOS 7.6 system here in the office where all users connect to and work on. But... there is a catch.
Default XRDP sessions work nicely in a way that from a single machine you always get back the session you were working on. But if you go to another 'workstation' from which you connect to this server you get a new session... Also if the same system but on a different network is used it ends up creating a new session.

I would like to have each user may create and re-use the same single session. (Cinnamon preferably). 
Other users should have a different session, but again that other user also just 1 single session.

In the /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini I added the secion:

```
[xrdp1]
name=sesman-Xvnc
lib=libvnc.so
username=user1
password=ask
ip=127.0.0.1
#port=ask-1
#port=ask5914
#port=5914
port=-1
```

It appear that only the option port=-1 seems to actualy open a session. ask-1 is working only 1 time, the other options ALWAYS gives me errors. From failed to open session on DISPLAY 0, to nothing at all.

The other options in the xrdp.ini file have been disabled.

the sesman.ini file is left alone.

setting a static port for 1 option [xrdp1] fixed to port x and [xrdp2] fixed to port y etc is an option, then I could create these sections for the 5 users I want to let them connect to and in the name mention the user for who it is. but fixed ports gave me the following error: "VNC error - problem connecting... some problem" (very vage).

Let me know if you have any suggestions I could try.

Regards,

Stefan

Comment: Have you got a solution on the mentioned issue?